Live action movie of boy and girl in mystical forest
I have been scouring the Internet for this movie. I'm certain it was B-rated and came out before 2015. I remember only one scene very vividly:
The boy/teen traps a rabbit in the woods and it starts screaming out of fear and the girl finds it to set it free and gets "caught" by him and his "side/tribe".
Later in the movie she escapes (?) but also traps a rabbit to lure the boy to talk him into being good.
I remember it being a very dimly lighted movie since it was in the forest. The boy had black/dark brown hair. The boy and girl were a love interest, I think.
And for some reason I believe at the end of the movie it shows a beautiful tree...
Definitely fantasy!! It was not modern day or historical.
The clothes were similar to robin hood style, or a castle setting. No technology whatsoever.
Whatever they were fighting over had some sort of mystical power, like maybe the tree gave off power?

What made this a fantasy film? Be as specific as you can.

Please republish my question  I don't know how to explain but it wasn't modern day, and im certain whatever they were fighting over had some sort of mystical power, like maybe the tree gave off power? I literally have no other memory of anything else, just because the part i remember isnt technically fantasy doesn't mean it wasn't a fanstasy movie.

Can you describe that rabbit trap?

yes! it was on the forest floor, kind of misty. it was made of wood or weaved I believe and it was over the rabbit with no bottom, all she had to do was undo the rope and open it up. If I'm thinking correctly she even picked the rabbit up to console it.

Probably "The Secret of Moonacre", a 2008 fantasy film based on Elizabeth Goudge's 1948 novel The Little White Horse.
The girl is Maria Merryweather (played by Dakota Blue Richards), who goes to live with relatives in Moonacre Valley after her father dies. The boy is Robin de Noir (Augustus Prew). The Merryweathers and de Noirs have a long-running feud which started when the families fought over some magical pearls belonging to the "Moon Princess", who was a de Noir and married a Merryweather. Seeing the greed in both families, the Princess cursed the valley to be plunged into eternal darkness if a "pure heart" does not undo the curse before the 5,000th full moon.
In the first scene you describe, the trap looks like a wooden cage and Robin is hiding with some cronies nearby. The de Noirs suspect that Maria might be able to undo the curse - though, at this point, she doesn't know this.  Robin's father wants the curse to happen in order to hurt the Merryweathers, even though his family owns land in the valley.
The de Noirs are depicted with a stereotypically evil aesthetic - wearing dark colours and living in an apparently unfinished fort, for example - while the Merryweathers live in an old but well-kept mansion and appear more genteel.

Oh my goodness!! Thank you so much! This is the movie!! I'm laughing so hard because what I remembered was like 2 mins of the entire movie and had nothing to do with anything else hahahaha. Thank you so much!
